# include jsp inside a jsp, how to remove include jsp when click a button in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I want to create a button to remove include jsp when on browser.

How to remove include jsp by clicking a button?

```
<jsp:include page="/test.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<jsp:include page="/test.jsp" />` happens on server side and you can only remove it in client side.You can use jQuery or Javascript to remove it.

Suppose the content of `test.jsp` is as below:

```
<div id="test">
 //other content
</div>
```

The you can remove like below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeInclude(this)">Remove</button>

function removeInclude(obj){
  $(obj).remove();
}
```

Note:if the content of `test.jsp` do not have more than one element as below,then you need to remove them one by one:

```
<div id="test1">
 //other content
</div>
<div id="test2">
 //other content
</div>
<div id="test3">
 //other content
</div>
```

in this case,you can use jQuery like `$("#test1,#test2,#test3").remove()`